# How to make nested routing in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

**HelloWorld.vue**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const router = () => axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b> id: {{ item.id }}</b>
      <router-link
        :to="`/${item.id}`"
      >
        {{ item.title }}
      </router-link>
    </div><!-- end v-for -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template> 

<script>
import { router } from "./router";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    router().then((r) => {
      this.items = r.data;
    }); 
  },
};
</script>
```

**User.vue**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const routerid = (itemId) =>
  axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/" + itemId);
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="item">
      <h1>Price: {{ item.price }}</h1>
    </div>
    <tabs />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { routerid } from "./routerid";
import tabs from "./tabs";
export default {
  name: "User",
  components: {
    tabs,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData();
  },
  computed: {
    routeId() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    routeId() {
      console.log("Reload (route change)");
      this.loadData();
    }, //reload when route id changes
  },

  methods: {
    loadData() {
      console.log("Reloading, ID", this.routeId);
      if (!this.routeId) return; // no ID, leave early
      routerid(this.$route.params.id).then((item) => {
        this.item = item.data;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**tabs.vue**

```js
import axios from "axios";

export const tabsandcontent = async (itemId) =>
  await axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=" + itemId);
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="item">
      <h1>description: {{ item.description }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { tabsandcontent } from "./tabsandcontent";
export default {
  name: "User",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadData();
  },
  computed: {
    tabsandcontent() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    tabsandcontent() {
      console.log("Reload (route change)");
      this.loadData();
    }, //reload when route id changes
  },

  methods: {
    loadData() {
      console.log("Reloading, ID", this.tabsandcontent);
      if (!this.tabsandcontent) return; // no ID, leave early
      tabsandcontent(this.$route.params.id).then((item) => {
        this.item = item.data;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**main.js**

```html
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";
import User from "./components/User";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/HelloWorld",
      name: "HelloWorld",
      component: HelloWorld,
      children: [{ path: ":id", name: "User", component: User }]
    }
  ]
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-41lh0f?file=/src/main.js

can you please answer this, In main.js routing I changed from path: "/" to path: "/HelloWorld" then all of sudden output not reflecting... because in my project path:'/' indicates login page??? In this scenario what changes, i need to make, to make logic work

also where is the relation between path:'/' and api call??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same name for the variables in tabs component (In watch and computed). And In tabsandcontent.js, you have missed to fetch description for the specific item as performed in routerId.js.

Have a look at modified version which is working as you expected.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/combined-logic-api-forked-ji5oh4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: can you please answer this, In main.js routing I changed from **path: "/"** to **path: "/HelloWorld"**  then all of sudden output not reflecting... because in my project path:'/' indicates login page??? 

In this scenario what changes, i need to make, to make logic work

Comment: this is the code after changes https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-41lh0f?file=/src/main.js

just changed path: "/HelloWorld"

Comment: The problem is you have to change the router link-to = `/HelloWorld/${item.id}`, after you change the url to /HelloWorld, because you've the children routes point to that main route.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, I want you to know that I don't understand what are you asking for. But I'm going to try to answer.

Your first question:

> In `main.js` routing I changed from `path: "/"` to `path: "/HelloWorld"` then all of sudden output not reflecting.

Yes, you will not see your `HelloWorld.vue` component. You can see your page however if you type `<your-url>/HelloWorld`. Usually the `/` path is used for something like "Home" page.

---

**However**, I've tried checking out your codesandbox. And take a look at your `HelloWorld.vue` component.

I think you are confused because when you changed the `path` from `/` to `/HelloWorld` apart from the `HelloWorld.vue` not showing up. It somehow broken the link which causes the API in `tabs.vue` not functioning.

If that's the case, you just have to simply add `HelloWorld/${item.id}` in `tabs.vue`,

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
      <b> id: {{ item.id }}</b>
      <router-link
        :to="`HelloWorld/${item.id}`" // --> Notice this line
      >
        {{ item.title }}
      </router-link>
    </div><!-- end v-for -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

This however, isn't a common thing to do routing. You should add your App URLs to `main.js`. Which also isn't common, but I'm assuming this is just a little reproduction code you made for StackOverflow.

Here are my CodeSandbox edits.
https://codesandbox.io/s/combined-logic-api-forked-jttt8p

I will update the answer again later, I'm still not on my personal laptop.